# Алгоритм поиска максимально близкого значения к числу

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть 6 чисел

```
20
17
15
2
30
3
```

И есть итоговое число 37. Подскажите алгоритм выбора элементов, который максимально быстро приблизится к числу 37 за наименьшее число итераций

Comment: `алгоритм выбора элементов` — имеется в виду, что максимально близкой должна быть сумма этих элементов?

Comment: @diraria да, найти максимально близкую сумму элементов к итоговому числу. В идеале >=

Comment: Ну, для шести элементов можно и перебор всех подмножеств за `O(2^6)=O(64)` написать...

Comment: ну по идее там будет ~1000 элементов

Comment: @diraria, человеку надо за наименьшее количество итераций, а это уже олимпиада.

Comment: Есть какое-нибудь ограничение на итоговое число? Скажем, оно до `10^6`

Comment: И еще, что вы называете итерацией? Определенный набор чисел не важно какой длины из всего множества? Или вас интересует в том числе наименьший набор из множества?

Answer (score 1):

То что вы описали есть ничто иное как задача о ранце и она очень хорошо подходит для генетического алгоритма, https://habrahabr.ru/post/128704/.
В ролике очень хорошо объясняется эта задача https://youtu.be/N0dZdCU1BrU?t=19m06s